# Setting manually the buildcontroller (unit test)

Tags: javascript, c#, unit-testing, tfs

I got a question regarding build controllers of Visual Studio. 
I got a project where I run multiple C# unit test. I currently implemented Javascript Unit tests to the project and I want to let the unit test be part of the build.

Several tutorials are available on the internet. [One of them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx) I used as guideline towards running JS intergrated within my TFS which is running on a buildserver.

The problem that I have is that the tutorial is saying that I should check in the files (of Chutzpah) and add the source file to the build controller. Here is my problem. Due to the fact that I do not want to affect all the other unit tests and build processes I can not modify the build controller. I can change any build definition but I can not change the ***"Version Control Path to custom Assemblies"***. So I was wondering is there alternative method where I still can make sure that JS unit tests are part of the build but not changing the version control path for the whole project?

I hope I stated my situation clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can enable your build process to leverage binaries that you have
>   uploaded to your Team Foundation Server, for example:
>
> - Assemblies that contain your custom workflow activities.
> - Third-party unit test frameworks. See Run tests in your build    process.
> - Custom MSBuild tasks
>
> To enable your build processes to leverage these kinds of code, upload
>   the binaries to the folder (or any of its descendant folders) that you
>   specify in the Version control path to custom assemblies box. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987.aspx)

So, if you haven't configured this path of your build control. It's easy, you just need to set a sever path. **This will not affect other unit tests and build processes** cuase they didn't even use this path before.

If there is aleady a server path, you just need to add the files mentioned in the tutorials into the source control with the same path. Just like a share folder, when the build definitions need the file, the build control will automatically find and call it in this path. When you set or modify the value in this box, the build server automatically restarts to load the assemblies.